# How can I make MarkupExtenstion for button click event in WPF 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.5

I want to create the MarkupExtension to provide support for Button click event. I have got an article for PreviewKeyDown [here](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/23/wpf-4-5s-markupextension-invoke-a-method-on-the-viewmodel-datacontext-when-an-event-is-raised/). I tried to modify it for Click but unable to do so as it throws an exception

Please suggest how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its trying to cast `MethodInfo` as `EventInfo`, the returned target property could be a `MethodInfo` or `EventInfo` you will have to check this before createing the delegate

Try this

```
    public class Call : MarkupExtension
    {
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public Call(string actionName) { ActionName = actionName; }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            IProvideValueTarget targetProvider = serviceProvider
                .GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;
            if (targetProvider == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(@"The CallAction extension 
                can't retrieved the IProvideValueTarget service.");

            var target = targetProvider.TargetObject as FrameworkElement;
            if (target == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(@"The CallAction extension 
                    can only be used on a FrameworkElement.");

            if (targetProvider.TargetProperty is MethodInfo)
            {
                var targetEventAddMethod = targetProvider.TargetProperty as MethodInfo;
                if (targetEventAddMethod != null)
                {
                    ParameterInfo[] pars = targetEventAddMethod.GetParameters();
                    Type delegateType = pars[1].ParameterType;
                    MethodInfo methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("MyProxyHandler", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    return Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, this, methodInfo); ;
                }

            }
            else if (targetProvider.TargetProperty is EventInfo)
            {
                var targetEventInfo = targetProvider.TargetProperty as EventInfo;
                if (targetEventInfo != null)
                {
                    Type delegateType = targetEventInfo.EventHandlerType;
                    MethodInfo methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("MyProxyHandler", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    return Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, this, methodInfo);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        void MyProxyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement target = sender as FrameworkElement;
            if (target == null) return;
            var dataContext = target.DataContext;
            if (dataContext == null) return;

            //get the method on the datacontext from its name
            MethodInfo methodInfo = dataContext.GetType()
                .GetMethod(ActionName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            methodInfo.Invoke(dataContext, null);
        }
    }
```